# infinite scrolling is not working in magento

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, infinite-scroll, magento-1.9

I have enabled infinite scroll in my magento site, but it is not working, previously it was working, don't know what happened. I am using milano magento theme. You can check it in this site. [this is my site's link](http://hercall.in/churidhar-materials/fancy-work-churidhar.html) when I inspected element it thorw an error says

> fancy-work-churidhar.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   ILLEGAL

Though I have submitted a ticket to the theme support system, I didn't get any reply till yet. And I am running out of time.  Can any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bogus characters in your file(s). The jQuery function has incorrect characters in it.

```
\n\t\t\/\/<![CDATA[\t\n\t\t\tjQuery(function($)
```

Check your extra jquery files for any bogus characters. Perhaps download jquery again and use that.

And check your layout xml files (e.g. `local.xml`). There may be something missing there, like a closing tag.

Seems to be a problem with the CDATA section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But i didn't add any new jquery to my theme file nor xml file.

Comment: Ok. It might be to do with encoding. Is it UTF8 encoded? Is <charset>utf8</charset> in the db config in local.xml?